# php - MySql - organizing variables for an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to fetch some rows from my db (php/mysql) and present them in a google chart using a javascript object as such:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Sales Price 1', 'Sales Price 2'],
      ['2013-05',  555, 651 ],
      ['2013-04',  1170, 321],
    ]);
```

I'm doing just one fetch from db ( SELECT PRICE1, PRICE2, DATE FROM transactions ).
 
Having trouble figuring out how to iterate through the rows to organize and print them out for the google javascript object..

I realize I have to do some php loops and count the variables for each month before echoing the results into the array, but I can't think of an appropriate way to compare the months.. 
any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to order your query by month or by price

Comment: Why do you need to compare the months?

Comment: Computing the total sum of "Price1" resp. "Price2" per month is a data related task and is therefore best performed by the database. What is the field type of "DATE"? If it's a MySQL Date or DateTime field, this should be fairly easy.

Comment: @COLD TOLD - After the query (just collecting all in the query), I'm trying to order sales by month.

Comment: @Explosion Pills - Maybe I'm not saying that right, I'm trying to order sales by month when printing into the javascript object

Comment: @bushdiver you can order by the date in the query, right?

Comment: @Niko the field type is date

Comment: @ExplosionPills sure, i can do something like: ORDER BY DATE DESC

Comment: @bushdiver just use order by http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: @COLDTOLD Oh.. that could work.. if i'm ordering by date, as the Date comes in i'll store the date as a string.. and if the string is the same on each row ill increment and add to that month.. and when the date changes I could go to the next place in the javascript array..

Comment: Try SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%M') as date, price1, price2 FROM transactions order by month(date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `ORDER BY` in the query for the dates (you apparently know this).  To create the array for JS, I would use JSON.

```
$values = array(array('MOnth', 'Sales Price 1', 'Sales Price 2'));
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $values[] = array_values($row);
}
$for_javascript = json_encode($values);
```

Answer (score 2):

With a DATE field containing the date of the transactions, you can easily obtain the total sums over the price fields grouped by month:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(date) AS year,
  MONTH(date) AS month,
  SUM(price1) AS total1,
  SUM(price2) AS total2
FROM transactions
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
ORDER BY date
```

This will most likely be much faster than a PHP solution, especially if there are a lot of transactions stored in that table.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/feddd/1